# Clarification for setting up SSH terminal access on Cisco IOS

Tags: cisco

I'm attempting to set up SSH on a Cisco 2811 and having some difficulties.

The first step to this should be running `crypto key generate rsa`

I seem to be missing this though:

```
better#crypto key generate rsa
                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

better#
```

Furthermore, the only available commands I have in the `crypto key` namespace are `lock` and `unlock`, which seem to indicate a locked keypair (for which I don't know the password):

```
better#crypto key ?
lock    Lock a keypair.
unlock  Unlock a keypair.

better#crypto key unlock ?
rsa  RSA keys

better#crypto key unlock rsa
%% Please enter the passphrase: 
%% Unlocking failed.
.

better#
```

More or less, I'm asking what exactly this might mean, and if I actually do have certificates already here (used router)? Otherwise, how can I solve this? It's my first time configuring this feature, but I definitely believe it's part of my IOS.

Speaking of my IOS, I'm running the image `c2800nm-advsecurityk9-mz.124-24.T6.bin`

I'll also note that I have my `hostname` and `ip domain-name` configured. I'll also give you a `dir flash:` below if it's at all of use:

```
better#dir flash:
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rw-        2748  Jul 27 2009 14:03:52 +00:00  sdmconfig-2811.cfg
    3  -rw-      931840  Jul 27 2009 14:04:10 +00:00  es.tar
    4  -rw-     1505280  Jul 27 2009 14:04:32 +00:00  common.tar
    5  -rw-        1038  Jul 27 2009 14:04:46 +00:00  home.shtml
    6  -rw-      112640  Jul 27 2009 14:05:00 +00:00  home.tar
    7  -rw-     1697952  Jul 27 2009 14:05:26 +00:00  securedesktop-ios-3.1.1.45-k9.pkg
    8  -rw-      415956  Jul 27 2009 14:05:46 +00:00  sslclient-win-1.1.4.176.pkg
    9  -rw-    38732900   Dec 8 2011 06:28:56 +00:00  c2800nm-advsecurityk9-mz.124-24.T6.bin

64016384 bytes total (20598784 bytes free)
better#
```

Comment: Resolution: Switch to global config mode. =(

Stackoverflow won't let me resolve it just yet because the question is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, being in the wrong mode:

```
better(config)#crypto key generate rsa
The name for the keys will be: better.malesky.org
Choose the size of the key modulus in the range of 360 to 2048 for your
  General Purpose Keys. Choosing a key modulus greater than 512 may take
  a few minutes.

How many bits in the modulus [512]: 
% Generating 512 bit RSA keys, keys will be non-exportable...[OK]

better(config)#
```

Comment: For ssh you will need keys of 768 bits in length probably, not 512. Also give the device a domain name and make sure its set to SSH version 2, with login period and failed auth count etc.